# Responsive navbar that hides and shows on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, responsive

I want to hide navbar onscroll, and then show it again 600px down. Im able to do that, but the responsive menu pops up on top even if im more than 600 px down on the page.

I'm a beginner, so i guess there is an obvious solution to this that i just can't see.

```
<script>
  // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
  window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

  function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 600) {
      document.querySelector(".navbar").style.top = "0";
    } else {
      document.querySelector(".navbar").style.top = "-70px";
    }
  }

  function resTopNav() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }

  function resNav() {
    var y = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
    if (y.className === "navbar") {
      y.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      y.className = "navbar";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Please see this pen for demo:
https://codepen.io/arnelamo/pen/jgYVag

It works fine except the hamburger on the popup navbar, which renders the menu on top of the page in stead of where it is actually clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your code correctly applies `position: fixed` to the navbar, but when you click the hamburger icon the JavaScript applies the `responsive` class to it. This, in turn, triggers the `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` selector, which has more [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than the `.navbar` selector.

To correct this, simply set `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` to have `position: fixed` instead of `position: relative`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  div.container {
    width: 970px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  div.container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  div.container {
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
  }
}





.headline {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 300px 15px 0px 15px;
}

.bg {
  background-color: black;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}


.crap {
  margin-top: 192px;
}

/* responsive top navbar*/

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* responsive main navbar */

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive {position: fixed;}
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* top navbar css */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.topnav a.active {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

/* main navbar css */

.navbar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: -70px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.navbar a.active {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- My CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#about">Projects</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="resTopNav()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bg">
      </div>

      <div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#news">Projects</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="resNav()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="headline">
        <h1>Guns don't kill people. <br> Chuck Norris kills people.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="crap">
        <div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px">
          <p><b>Chuck Norris doesn't get put behind bars.Bars get put behind Chuck Norris.</b></p>

          <p>When Chuck Norris sets his watch, he sets time itself, When Chuck Norris is in the same room as a chess board, his name becomes 'Bobby Fischer' Chuck Norris is the only man to ever defeat a brick wall in a game of tennis Chuck Norris will attain statehood in 2009. His state flower will be the Magnolia. Chuck Norris can win a game of Connect Four in only three moves Chuck Norris doesn't face his fears, his fears face him Chuck Norris doesn't churn butter. He roundhouse kicks the cows and the butter comes straight out, There is no theory of evolution. Just a list of creatures Chuck Norris has allowed to live Chuck Norris doesn't read books. He stares them down until he gets the information he wants, Police label anyone attacking Chuck Norris as a Code 45-11... a suicide, If you ask Chuck Norris what time it is, he always says, "Two seconds 'til." After you ask, "Two seconds 'til what?" he roundhouse kicks you in the face.</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
      // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
      window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

      function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 600) {
          document.querySelector(".navbar").style.top = "0";
        } else {
          document.querySelector(".navbar").style.top = "-70px";
        }
      }

      function resTopNav() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }

      function resNav() {
        var y = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
        if (y.className === "navbar") {
          y.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          y.className = "navbar";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note, however, that this also messes up the expanded navbar on mobile devices at the top of the page. As such, you may want to make this change through JavaScript based on the `height` (as you have done with the showcasing on the navbar).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for your response. It seems to work exactly as planned, and i can't see that it messes up the expanded navbar at the top, actually. It seems to wok fine.

Comment: However, i see that the expanded navbar actually pushes the rest of the divs on the page down when it expands. Any ideas of how to resolve this issue? Do i have to write js that pushes everything up when the icon i clicked, or is it an easier way to solve this that i'm to noob to see? :D